# How to chage ngx-bar chart color using customColor?

Tags: javascript, charts, angular-material, ngx-charts

I am trying to change the colour of my ngx bar chart by calling a function at [customColor] property but it is going into loop even though by animation mode is off.

I had referred to the following StackOverflow answer and even on a comment section, someone is facing the same issue.

[How to use Ngx-Charts customColor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765823/how-to-use-ngx-charts-customcolor-function)

[setTimeOut Handler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqoZl.png)

I had console the text msg 'custom colours called' inside CustomColor() function.
(which I called at [customColor]=CustomColor())

apart from it, it's working absolutely fine but not sure why it is going into loop ??
Because of the same, my system get down after a couple of minutes

[console msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkqMD.png)

would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can we see some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

We should avoid binding function to the property, as it gets trigger every time whenever change detection happens.

I would recommend fetching custom colors to a public array in ngOnit and bind this array to [customColor] property.

```
customColors: any[] = [];
constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.customColors = this.getCustomColors();
}

getCustomColors() {
  //retrun customColor;
}

// In template
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
  [animations]="barAnimations"
  [customColors]="customColors"
  ...
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```